# Help with a question on write-through and no-write allocate in caches

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I am struggling with this question as I am not sure whether the answer that has been provided is correct or not. The image should be sufficient to tell the question.

The attached image is of the answer. For the question, imagine all but the first two columns are empty.[image]

Here's what I am struggling with:

1. Why is when the address 8500 referenced, a "miss". From my understanding, since it shares the same tag and index value with the address 8496, it should be a "hit".

2. Why is it a "miss" when the address 304 is referenced again. Since it was a "miss" the first time, it would have been loaded in the cache and then when called again it should be a "hit". Is this not how it works?

Comment: 1: no-write-allocate means the write to 8496 does not insert a cache block. 2: two other blocks were inserted at the same index between 304 references, in a 2-way LRU cache this means a conflict miss.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Oh yeah that makes sense. I completely missed the no-write-allocate and the second answer also makes things clear. Thank you.